# High disk usage windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, memory, ssd

i already read a lot of about 100% disk usage(50% because i have second disk) on windows machines but nothing help me. I figured out that i need to stop svchost.exe and ntdll.dll in it. Hovewer when i stop this service network stop working for some time and killing srervice dont solve my problem. I already update windows, disable prefetch. You can see service on image.

HW: intel i7 4710HQ, 256GB SSD, 16GB RAM OS: Windows 8.1 x64

[image]

ETL file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8j7G6Ql6xXvekJLQU9IU0ZaanM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Install the WPT (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and click to start. Now capture 1 minute of the DiskIO. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: Do you have an actual problem? Is performance poor, for example?

Comment: Yes, system is always slow(not dramatically) and disk 0 usage is 100%. Also fan always working in contrast with svchost.exe killed.

Comment: ok, I looked at the ETL and posted an answer. Next time, please Zip the file, to dramatically reduce the file size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkin the trace for [CPU usage](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis), I can see that the CPU usage comes from `srumsvc.dll!SruWorkQueueThreadPoolCallback` which later calls some `esent.dll` functions.

[image]

[SRUM stands for "System Resource Usage Monitor"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6-83WU95Sw).

> Windows 8 and Windows 10 has a newly added feature to track system
>   resource usage, specifically process and network metrics over time.
>   Process related information such as process owner, CPU cycles used,
>   data bytes read/written, and network data (sent/received) are
>   continuously recorded by a mechanism called System Resource Usage
>   Monitor (SRUM).

This is a component which is part of the `Diagnostic Policy Service`. Watch the video and read the linked PDF for a detailed look what the `System Resource Usage Monitor`is.

[Checking the trace for DiskIO](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis), I see that the disk IO happens to file `C:\Windows\System32\sru\SRUDB.dat` which is the database of the SRUM service which also explains the ESET Database calls, which cause CPU usage.

[image]

So, if you don't use metered connection or want statistics about network, CPU usage in Taskmgr you can try to disable the `Diagnostic Policy Service`.

Comment: Thank you very much i disable `Diagnostic Policy Service` and it works fine. @magicandre1981